# Is it possible to add dynamic option to SettingsPane?

Tags: gluon-mobile

I use a SettingsPane to manage application settings. I want the user to be able create any number of Account option. This is a parent option which have children options like name, server, port, user and password. Each of them has extended description. If I add a new option through a button, SettingsPane doesn't show new option in the list. My first approach was to try to recreate SettingsView but SettingsPane creates additional views named Group_View_[Option Caption]_0_1 and Extended_View_[Option Caption]_1_2 which must be removed before recreating the SettingsView otherwise it throws an error like 'View  must be unique'.

Is it possible to reload a view once it is created or to add dynamic options to SettingsPane?

Comment: So far this is not possible, but an issue has been filed and it will be solved in the incoming next release of Gluon Mobile. Any change to the Options observable list will be immediately rendered.